# Monte Carlo calculation of value at risk

Tags: monte-carlo, risk

I want to calculate the VaR with Monte Carlo Simulation, I am referring to this page:

http://financetrain.com/calculating-var-using-monte-carlo-simulation/

which was created to the JP Morgan desrciption:

http://www.jpmorgan.com/tss/General/Risk_Management/1159380637650

Now I have several questions, where I could not find any answer:
The "random variable $\varphi$ generated from a normal distribution": Why is it from a normal distribution? I thought it should be from a uniform variable which is then transformed by plugging it in into the standard stock price model with the corresponding sample mean and sample variance?

Standard stock price model:
$R_i=\frac{(S_{i+1}-S_i)}{S_i}=\mu \Delta t + \sigma \varphi \sqrt{\Delta t}$

The Monte Carlo Simulation has mathematical connection to Kolmogorovs Strong Law of Large Numbers. Could you explain me this in this context? Is the following correct: I simulate 1000 final prices, the estimator of the mean (sample average of all final prices) will converge to the real unknown mean, this is K SLLN right? The final stock prices will be normal distributed, but due to the fact that the random number is from a normal distribution and the stock price model function is just a linear transformation or because of the central limit theorem? If this is not correct, what does Monte Carlo has to do with the Central Limit Theorem?

Also I have at the end approx. 1000 stock pathes with the final stock prices. I am going to plot those and is it ok, if I "underlay" a normal distribution graphically at the end of the plot for the final stock prices? So these should be normal distributed right? Again: Is this a consequence of K SLLN or due to the random number generation from a normal distribution?

A lot of questions also a lot of not understanding, so thanks for your answers if you answer.